# How to set a breakpoint to the end of a function in TRACE32?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I want to set a breakpoint to the end of a function in Lauterbach.

I know that this can be achieved using Break.set sYmbol.EXIT(function_name).

Unfortunately, this isn't working.

Can you indicate another command for this ?

Comment: `Break.set sYmbol.EXIT(function_name)` is in fact the correct approach. If this is not working there might be a bug in your version of TRACE32 or you are trying to debug optimized code.

Comment: For some of the functions I get the message "variable has no address"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set breakpoint at the end of the function, you can use 
**g.r** command. This command will run the program till the **return** statement of the function.

Comment: Note that `Go.Return` will set a **temporary breakpoint**, which will be removed when the CPU stops (no matter where it stops). Anyway, in most cases this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `BREAK.SET sYmbol.END(function_name)`, I had the same error and this fixed it.

Comment: Nope. `sYmbol.END(function_name)` returns the highest address occupied by the function. However this does not have to be the address of the last instruction executed. To get the last instruction executed use `sYmbol.EXIT(function_name)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just started scripting with lauterbach so I don't know much about it. Do you happen to know why the error "variable has no address" comes up when I use sYmbol.EXIT(function_name)? Does it have to do with the fact that the function is void?

Comment: Maybe your function got inlined, so there is no longer an exit point. Are you debugging optimized code?